# Uploading multiple images with drag and drop in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I would like to make a function on my website where the user can upload, for example, 10, 20 or 100 images(in bulk) with drag and drop (or just upload) from his computer and all the uploaded images will be displayed there.

If anyone has any tips, documentation, or github repos, I'd appreciate it, thanks a lot.

The function looks something like https://www.remove.bg/upload

I am attaching a screenshot from that page: